# Rewrite Game of Life as a convolution and a nonlinearity

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, cellular-automata

If you implement Conway's Game of Life on a computer, it's convenient to define the neighbor-counting kernel,
$$
k = \left[ \begin{array}{} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right]
$$
If $u_t$ is the state at time $t$, then the convolution $k*u_t$ is the number of neighbors. Define $f:\mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ by
$$
f(u_0,u_1) = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } (u_0,u_1) \in \{ (0,3), (1,2), (1,3) \} \\
0, & \text{else} 
\end{cases}
$$
We can then write express 1 time step of Game of Life as
$$u_{t+1} := f\circ(u_t, k*u_t)$$
Here is the question: can you instead find $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ and a kernel $k:\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that the map $u \mapsto f \circ (k*u)$ is the Game of Life rule?

Answer (score 9):

Yes! Define
$$
k = \left[ \begin{array}{} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 9 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right]
$$
and
$$
f(u) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } u \in \{3, 11, 12\} \\
0 & \text{else} 
\end{cases}
$$
This corresponds to the previous parameterization via $(0,3)\to 3$, $(1,2)\to 11$, $(1,3)\to 12$. This works because $k*u_t(x)\geq9$ guarantees $u_t(x)=1$, and likewise $k*u_t(x)<9$ guarantees $u_t(x)=0$, with $k*u_t(x)\bmod 9$ being the neighbor count.

Comment: Another option would be $k = \left[ \begin{array}{} 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \end{array} \right]$ with $f(u) = 1$ iff $5 \le u \le 7$.

Comment: Isn't this  $f(k*u)$, rather than $k * f(u)$ as OP asked?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni My bad, the original post asked for $f(k*u)$ before edits. Finding $k*f(u)$ would be interesting.